# node --inspect-brk with Nuxt + Typescript + Jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, nuxt.js, node-inspector

I am using Nuxt + Typescript + Jest.
I tred to [Troubleshooting of Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting#tests-are-failing-and-you-dont-know-why), but I got following error:

```
$ node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/xxxx
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Determining test suites to run.../bin/sh: nuxt-ts: command not found
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

Could you help me!

Comment: Did you ever solve the `nuxt-ts: command not found` issue?

Comment: @AndyRowland did you find a solution?

Comment: I don't think the latest Nuxt requires the Nuxt TS runtime anymore.  Not sure if this solved it or the project just moved on.  Sorry, I can't even remember what the problem was.